# Rails undefined method ReactJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I am getting an error on my application `undefined method 'preference' for #<User:0x007fb3cc1c3b80>`. Following were my `accounts` controller:

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController

    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def edit
        #render html: 'Edit your account'
        render component: 'AccountsEdit', props: {
            preference: PreferenceSerializer.new(current_user.preference)
        }, tag: 'div'
    end

    def update
        @preference = current_user.preference
        if @preference.update_attributes(preference_params)
            render json: { data: 'SUCCESS!' }
        else
            render json: { data: 'FAIL!' }
        end
    end

    private 
        def preference_params
            params.require(:preference).permit(:display_name, :notify_on_answer, :daily_digest)
        end


end
```

And my User and Preference model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end

class Preference < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Seems all look alright, but i keep getting the same error. Am i missing something here? Thanks!!

Comment: you are missing how the User is associated to Preference like has_many :preferences or has_a :preference line in User model.

Comment: @d3bug3r, If you feel my answer helped [solved your issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), please mark it as ‘[accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)' by clicking the green check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. This will help the community to keep the focus on unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `User` model add the relation to the `Preference` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_a: :preference # Or has_many: :preferences
end
```